# Copy specific paragraphs from a page using button, using react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying to implement this design below[image]

as you can see there are multiple copy buttons on each paragraph. How can I copy each specific paragraph

Here is the code for the design

```
<Stack spacing={3} ml={7} w="90%">
                <Text fontSize={40} fontWeight="bold" mt="60px" mb="10px">Your Product Listing</Text>
                <Flex direction="row" align="center">

                    <Text id='title' fontSize="32px" fontWeight="semibold"><Link color="#18A9FB" href='#'>Fleur de Sel</Link> - Premium Sea salt from Guerande France - <Link color="#18A9FB" href='#'>Flaky Sea Salt </Link> from the Celtic Sea - Salt Cork box - 3.5 Oz (100g)
                    </Text>
                    <Button variant='link' _hover={{
                        textDecoration: 'none',
                    }} > <Icon as={AiOutlineReload} mr={2} ml={4} boxSize={8} /> </Button>
                    <Button onClick={(e) => copyText(e)} variant='link' _hover={{
                        textDecoration: 'none',
                    }}>  <Icon as={MdContentCopy} mr={2} boxSize={8} /> </Button>

                </Flex>
                <UnorderedList spacing={4}>
                    <ListItem>
                        AUTHENTIC HAND HARVESTED SALT: Tablissima french sea salt is carefully harvested by hand from the surface of salt ponds in the Guérande region of France. Centuries-old harvesting techniques are used to harvest a 100% natural salt that will provide a delicate taste to your food and make every bite delicious.
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        ARTISANAL SEA SALT: Our Guérande Fleur de Sel is classified as IGP (Protected Geographical Indication), which guarantees you its origin, its natural production method and it's harvesting techniques. Our salt comes from a production with no pesticides, nor herbicides, no fossil nor carbon Energy.
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        CAVIAR OF SALT: This finishing salt is loved by the best culinary professionals. Rich in minerals and lower in sodium than regular salt, it will give a delicate and subtle taste to any of your favourite dishes.
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        MADE IN FRANCE: Our sea salt is harvested on the salt marshes of Guérande in France. Delicately picked from the surface of the water, it’s neither washed nor treated and drips naturally on our salt flats. Trusted by the best Chefs.
                    </ListItem>
                </UnorderedList>
            </Stack>
```